How to bound generalization error of a shallow NN?
I have a trained one-hidden layer NN with ReLU. There are 2N+d parameters in total (N is the number of nodes and d is the number of dimension). The sample size to train this NN is exactly N.
Now, in this special case, I have a method to make sure that optimization error is exactly 0 (i.e. squared loss is 0)
Due to the special relationship between number of parameters and sample size, it is difficult for me to bound the generalization error. Please give me some hints. Thanks .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
